# advance tcsh complete. using older decisions to influence further

Tags: shell, tcsh, tab-completion

I want to make some complete that use like that:

```
my_setup -project
```

when hit TAB it will show me the project options:

```
proj1 proj2 proj3
```

after choosing proj1

```
my_setup -project proj1 -step
```

when hit TAB it will show me the step options in selected project

```
steps options for proj1:    step0 step1.3 step9.0
steps options for proj2:    step0.0
steps options for proj3:    step55
```

I start with:

```
complete my_setup "c/-/(project step)/" \
    'n/-help/n/' \
    'n/-project/`echo $PROJ_OPT`/ ' \
    'p/1/x:<Exampleof use>/ '
```

it show me option for the project but i dont know how to let how know what the steps after user chose project.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can define such context-aware completion rule, but perhaps you can combine the project and step options into one option?
I have used this approach before.

This can look something like:

```
% my_setup -project-step <TAB>
proj1:step0 proj1:step1.3 proj1:step9.0 proj2:step0.0 proj3:step55
```

Using the following `complete` command (and using a new env variable `PROJ_STEP_OPT` which you need to set accordingly):

```
complete my_setup "c/-/(project step)/" \
    'n/-help/n/' \
    'n/-project-step/`echo $PROJ_STEP_OPT`/ '
```